# Hide label when UITableView Cell is tapped

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have a label within my cells that I would like to show/hide when tapped. I know that I have to get the index path of the cell that was tapped from within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. But I am unsure of how I then show/hide the label in that particular cell.

Am I able to show/hide it from within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, or is there a way to deal with it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then update it?

I did some research into this but I really couldn't find a whole lot.

Here is all I have so far:

```
var selectedRowIndex: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: -1, inSection: 0)

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRowIndex = indexPath
}
```

Comment: You can get cell from `didSelectRowIndexPath`. `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` and than hide label of this cell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is how you get to the cell from the index path:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as MyCustomCell
cell.myTextLabel.hidden = true
```

Also, depending on your needs, you might want to deselect the cell as well.

```
tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Comment: Great! I didn't realise it was that simple. Thanks a lot.